# How to display only the specified coordinates of image at the centre of DIV container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have an image of 1108px height and 907 px height. I have kept this image in a div tag and its height and width is as shown

```
<div id="mapframe" style="overflow:hidden;height:200px;width:300px;">
<img id="image"  src="img/Groundfloor1.jpg"  height="1108px" width="907px">
</div>
```

Now i do not know how to display only the specified coordinates(eg **500px from top and 100px from right**) of my image at the centre of the div container and the image should be a **DRAGGING IMAGE like GOOGLE MAPS**. I have tried it with offset but the problem with it is that my image stops dragging.
Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be an image element? It might be easier having it as a `background-image` for the div and using `background-position` to move it around.

If you insist on having an `img` element, you could also use margins, but to save you some headaches I would just use absolute positioning.